# Why is Terminal.app corrupting my tcsh history?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

I've had an ongoing problem that appears to be specific to OS X and Terminal.app: periodically, I get garbage in my tcsh history that looks like this:

```
^[[1m^[[4mcomputername:~/Code/emacs-source ( 1827 ) $^[[0m^[[24m logout
```

Somehow my prompt (including markup control characters) is getting stored as part of the command history. In my .history file, the corrupt commands are repeated with the same command number:

```
#+1391563259
[1m[4mcomputername:~/Code/emacs-source ( 1827 ) $[0m[24m
#+1391563259
Use "logout" to logout.
#+1391563259
[1m[4mcomputername:~/Code/emacs-source ( 1827 ) $[0m[24m logout
```

This seems to be a result of closing Terminal.app windows and tabs, but I'm not sure why. To fix it -- since I have history merging enabled -- I've had to resort to closing all tcsh sessions and removing the corrupt commands from .history. Is there some way to prevent this from happening in the first place?

Comment: this is not a concrete solution, but did you consider switching to iTerm2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten about this issue, but here's an update. The tcsh savehist merge feature is not atomic, so closing multiple sessions simultaneously can lead to history file corruption:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=632892

I don't know if this has been fixed or will be fixed; I finally got fed up of this and other tcsh issues and switched to bash.

Answer (score 0):

Are you cutting/pasting commands and picking up some of your prompt by accident?

It's not quite the answer you're looking for but throw ***sed -i.bak -e "s/\x1b[[0-9;]{1,5}m//g" .history*** into your .logout or cron it and you shouldn't have to clean it manually again.